# Why does IIS seem to be elevating the WindowsIdentity of one request from the AppPool to my user account?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, windows-identity

I am currently working on an ASP .NET application which involves the user logging in using Windows Authentication. This causes both the HTTPContext.User and Thread.Principal to be set with the same credentials as the user logging in which is expected behaviour, while the WindowsIdentity stays as the IIS .NET AppPool user.

I have recently noticed in the application logs that there appears to be one request (normally the 5th-ish request on loading the page) where the WindowsIdentity starts off as the IIS user but ends up being elevated to the user who is logging in.

This only appears to be happening when the user is accessing the root path (for instance http://localhost/). If I specify any other exact path such as http://localhost/index.aspx this request does not appear to occur and the WindowsIdentity never changes.

Looking through the (rather large) codebase I can only find one method that impersonates a WindowsIdentity, but that method is not called apart from in specific circumstances on a specific page.

I was wondering why this might be happening and if there was any reason that IIS might be doing it by itself.

Answer (score 1):

As per me i think the root(http://localhost) access is only for the administrator user , so it is checking where it is administrator user or not .. ,is the http://loclahost accessible if the user in not the administrator user ?

Comment: It makes no difference whether the user is administrator or not. The URL http://localhost/ should just use the default document (http://localhost/index.aspx) and send that instead. I'm trying to discover whether this is something that IIS does (either intentionally or as a side-effect) or if it is something code-specific.